# LLVM IR - How does a personality function work?

Tags: clang, llvm, llvm-ir

I've been playing around with making my own language using LLVM and I'm trying to add some basic exception handling. The rules of my language are to have one top level place to handle exceptions, so effectively the whole program is wrapped in a try/catch but you can't define them anywhere else.

I'm having some issues implementing the personality function part of this though. I haven't gotten very far though, and have been struggling to find any good documentation on this.

My LLVM IR looks like this:

```
; ModuleID = 'NativeBinary'
source_filename = "NativeBinary"
target datalayout = "e-m:e-i64:64-f80:128-n8:16:32:64-S128"
target triple = "x86_64-unknown-none"

@toPrint = private unnamed_addr constant [18 x i8] c"In personality %d\00"
@toPrint.1 = private unnamed_addr constant [18 x i8] c"In personality %d\00"
@toPrint.2 = private unnamed_addr constant [18 x i8] c"In personality %d\00"
@toPrint.3 = private unnamed_addr constant [9 x i8] c"In catch\00"
@globstr = private unnamed_addr constant [15 x i8] c"Running... %d\0A\00"
@globstr.4 = private unnamed_addr constant [4 x i8] c"%d\0A\00"

define i32 @main() personality i32 (i32, i32, i64, i8*, i8*)* @"__gxx_personality_v0" {
entry:
  %calltmp = invoke i32 @Main()
          to label %then unwind label %catch

then:                                             ; preds = %entry
  ret i32 0

catch:                                            ; preds = %entry
  %landingpad = landingpad <{ i8*, i32 }>
          cleanup
  call void @printf(i8* getelementptr inbounds ([9 x i8], [9 x i8]* @toPrint.3, i32 0, i32 0), i32 0)
  ret i32 1
}

declare void @printf(i8*, i32)

define i32 @Main() {
entry:
  %calltmp = call i8* @llvm.stacksave()
  call void @printf(i8* getelementptr inbounds ([15 x i8], [15 x i8]* @globstr, i32 0, i32 0), i32 0)
  %deref = load i32, i32* addrspacecast (i32 addrspace(64)* null to i32*)
  call void @printf(i8* getelementptr inbounds ([4 x i8], [4 x i8]* @globstr.4, i32 0, i32 0), i32 %deref)
  call void @llvm.stackrestore(i8* %calltmp)
  ret i32 0
}

define i32 @"__gxx_personality_v0"(i32 %version, i32 %actions, i64 %exceptionClass, i8* %unwind_exception, i8* %context) {
entry:
  call void @printf(i8* getelementptr inbounds ([18 x i8], [18 x i8]* @toPrint, i32 0, i32 0), i32 %version)
  call void @printf(i8* getelementptr inbounds ([18 x i8], [18 x i8]* @toPrint.1, i32 0, i32 0), i32 %actions)
  %cast = trunc i64 %exceptionClass to i32
  call void @printf(i8* getelementptr inbounds ([18 x i8], [18 x i8]* @toPrint.2, i32 0, i32 0), i32 %cast)
  ret i32 1
}

; Function Attrs: nounwind
declare i8* @llvm.stacksave() #0

; Function Attrs: nounwind
declare void @llvm.stackrestore(i8*) #0

attributes #0 = { nounwind }
```

Compiling with Clang 15.0 on Windows and running locally, I get
`Running... 0 In personality -451349008In personality -451348432In personality -451350272In personality -451349008In personality -451348432In personality -451352016`

I took the format of the personality function from https://itanium-cxx-abi.github.io/cxx-abi/abi-eh.html#base-personality. I've added some debugging printf statements to see what the inputs are to my personality function when it's called, but I'm just getting garbage numbers out. My understandind is that these are required to determine the result/transfer control to a landing pad.

My main questions are:

- Is this function meant to take inputs? If so, is there any reason mine would be coming out with garbage?
- Is a personality function meant to directly transfer control to the landing pad, or is this handled by the LLVM backend based on the result from my personality function?
- Is there any other way I can do something like this? I want to be able to catch segmentation faults if possible

Let me know if I've left anything out.

Thanks.